# what incentive is there for a mobile APP to NOT have a desktop / browser version?

Tags: android, ios, web, mobile, browser

I notice a lot of popular mobile APPs don't have a website version. What reason is this? For example, the popular dating APP Tinder doesn't have a web version.

Comment: Tinder has a web version

Answer (score 1):

- Development cost: targeting another platform takes up precious time and resources
- Audience size: how many people would actually use the desktop version? Probably not that many, compared to the mobile version
- Competing priorities: even if a desktop version is desirable for a company, is it more important than other things, like (in the case of Tinder) implementing new features in their app? Maybe, maybe not!
- Market positioning: my bank is only accessible via an app- there's no way of accessing banking via a computer. Part of this is about the reasons listed above, but I think part of it has to be that they are trying to position themselves as the bank for young people, and this is just one more (albeit extreme) way of making that idea clear in the eyes of consumers

Hope this helps!

Note: Even though this is a thing, it must be noted that [Tinder, does, in fact, have a web version](https://tinder.com/) (though not a desktop app to the best of my knowledge)